# Split string by a complete string separator

Tags: c#, string, split

I need to split a string, for example AAA@AAA_@#@*BBBBBB*@#@*CCCCCC, using as separator the complete string "*_@#@_". The result i'm looking for is:

> [0] AAA@AAA
>
> [1]
>
> [2] BBBBBB
>
> [2]
>
> [3] CCCCCC

I'm doing the following:

```
char[] sep = FIELD_SEPARATOR.ToCharArray();
ArrayList result = new ArrayList();
string[] fields = line.Split(sep);
```

Where FIELD_SEPARATOR is the string "_*@#@*"
The thing is that i'm getting 2 records for the first field, and the "@" char is deleted from them.

> [0] AAA
>
> [1] AAA
>
> ...

Is there a way to do it? I'm using .NET Framework 1.1

Thanks in advance!

Comment: Your first example does not make sense. 1) What are the numbers inside []? 2) The string "@#@_" never occurs in your source. 3) Even if the separator is "@#@", there is an extraneous "_" there that disappeared. You should clarify this.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This should also work for you:

```
string[] bits = Regex.Split("AA@AAA_@#@BBBBBB@#@CCCCCC", "@#@");
```

Answer (score 6):

Does this not work?

```
string[] fields = line.Split(new string[] {"@#@"}, StringSplitOptions.None);
```

Comment: The .Split() method only allows me as parameter a char[], I'm using .NET framework 1.1

Answer (score 4):

if,

```
string oldstring="AAA@AAA_@#@BBBBBB@#@CCCCCC";
```

then,

```
string[] parts = System.Text.RegularExpressions.Regex.Split(oldstring,"@#@");
```

This will give ,

parts[0]=AAA@AAA_

parts[1]=BBBBBB

parts[2]=CCCCCC

Will that Suffice...........

Comment: The correct way to format code is with four spaces at the start of the line, not with a `>` (that's for quotes). Refer to the [Markdown Editing Help](http://stackoverflow.com/editing-help) page for more information.

Comment: Thanks Martinho Fernandes Sir for editing....I was in too much of a hurry to note that...Sorry for that :)

Answer (score 0):

To be more correct

```
line.Split(new string[] { "@#@" }, StringSplitOptions.None)
```